# C#: Need to check if file array is empty

Tags: c#

I am checking for files in two locations. If location 1 is empty, the code should check location 2.

The problem is that the "files == null" condition is never met.

I need a better way to check if the files array is empty.

Here is my code:

```
files = Directory.GetFiles(fileTargetFolder);

if (files == null)  // if no files, check 2nd location
{
    files = Directory.GetFiles(fileTargetFolder2);
}
```

Comment: One followup. There are definitely no files in folder 1. I have code to clear out junk files like Thumbs.db.

Comment: The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2.aspx) says: "If there are no files, this method returns an empty array."
An empty array is not equal to null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check `Length` property of array.

```
if(files.Length == 0)
{
     files = Directory.GetFiles(fileTargetFolder2);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check for length

```
if (files.Length==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use p/invoke with [PathIsDirectoryEmpty function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773623.aspx)

```
        [DllImport("Shlwapi.dll", EntryPoint = "PathIsDirectoryEmpty")]
        [return : MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool IsDirectoryEmplty([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string directory);
```